# Difficulty in understanding Kotlin Coroutine output

Tags: kotlin, asynchronous, kotlin-coroutines, coroutine

```
fun main() {
    println("Start of program")
    GlobalScope.launch{

        println("Starting coroutine")
        val result = someOperation()
        println("Coroutine Running thread is: ${Thread.currentThread().name}")
        println("Coroutine completed with result: $result")
        println("End of the coroutine function")

    }
    println("End of program")
}

suspend fun someOperation(): String { //This is a coroutine now (Due to suspend modifier).
    delay(3000) // long-running operation
    return "Operation performed successfully"
}
```

Can someone explain me why am I getting this as my output ?

```
Start of program
End of program
```

Whereas the expected output was :

```
Start of program
Starting coroutine
Coroutine Running thread is: DefaultDispatcher-worker-1
Coroutine completed with result: Operation performed successfully
End of the coroutine function
End of program
```

If coroutines are meant to run on background thread, why the coroutine is not even getting called in the above case ?

According to me, the main function should get fired at first, and it should spawn the coroutine (eventually thread) and at least after completing the main function, the program should give the chance for coroutine to complete before exiting.

**P.S:**
I am a lot struggling with coroutine and asynchronous programming. Please if anyone has a good resource for the same, sharing it would be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Launching a coroutine queues it to start running asynchronously. As it is getting started, your main function continues synchronously. When it returns, the app has completed and so it terminates. If you want your app to stay open to wait for the coroutine to finish, you need to call `join()` on the Job returned by `launch`. To do this in `main` you need to either mark `main` as a suspend function or surround all of its code in `runBlocking { }` so you can call suspend functions inside it.

Alternatively, if you use `runBlocking` you can directly launch a child coroutine without GlobslScope, and then you won’t have to call `join()` on it. `runBlocking` automatically waits for all its children coroutines to finish.

Comment: But if coroutine is executing parallelly, at least I should get to see some statement executed from it till the point main thread has completed execution. Why even that is not happening ?

Comment: You only have one trivial line of code after the coroutine. That will be finished almost instantaneously. It’s a race condition. It’s possible you might see one line of the coroutine get executed but that’s extremely unlikely because the coroutine has to be passed to a thread before it can even start, which is a more CPU intensive amount of work than a `println` call, and even if it only took 1ms, it’s already behind the start time of that `println` call after the coroutine before it’s even ready to start running it’s own code.

Answer (score 1):

If you look into the documentation of [GlobalScope](https://kotlinlang.org/api/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines/-global-scope/) it says explicitly that:

> Active coroutines launched in GlobalScope do not keep the process alive. They are like daemon threads.

But this is not really specific to `GlobalScope`. Coroutines generally don't keep the process alive. Threads do. Coroutines were designed around the concept of the structured concurrency where tasks consist of smaller subtasks and wait for them to finish. If we launch a coroutine, but we don't observe it in any way, it is not a part of a bigger task, etc., then this is like we don't really need this coroutine anymore. This is similar to allocating an object and not storing a reference to it anywhere.

Common pattern when using coroutines is to start by calling `runBlocking()` in the `main()` and using it as a "root" coroutine which is a parent of all/most coroutines running in the application. This way we can easily make sure we don't leak any background tasks, we can cancel all tasks of the whole application, etc.